# jspファイルでif文を利用して条件が一致したらボタンを表示させたい。

Tags: java

以下コードで「sessionScope.login_employee.id」と「reportfavo.employee.id」の値がイコールの時「いいね取り消し」ボタンを表示させたいです。
「sessionScope.login_employee.id」と「reportfavo.employee.id」の値を確認したら同じ値だったのですが「いいね取り消しボタンが」表示されません。どこか不備があればご教示いただけますでしょうか。

```
<c:if test="${ sessionScope.login_employee.id == reportfavo.employee.id } ">
            <form method="POST" action="<c:url value='/reports/destroy' />">
                <p align="justify">
                    <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="${report.id}" />
                    <button type="submit">いいね取り消し</button>
                </p>
            </form>
        </c:if>
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/209528

Comment: マルチポスト先によると解決済みで、 `id` が `String` 型であるため `==` でなく `equals` で比較する必要があった、ようです。

Answer (score 0):

上記のコードから

```
<c:if test="${ sessionScope.login_employee.id == reportfavo.employee.id } ">
```

と

```
</c:if>
```

を消しても、ボタンが表示されなければ、分岐条件（`c:if`）の問題ではないです。

`c:if`の問題であれば、以下の2行を追加して、値を確認することで本当に一致しているのかが分かります。

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.login_employee.id}"/>
<c:out value="${reportfavo.employee.id}"/>
```